# Android NDK works on Android or requires a custom android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm a little confused on how the NDK functions, do I have to repackage android with my NDK code, or can any code developed with Android sdk, extend itself with the NDK, meaning the code compiles and can be run on any suitable(depending on api of the sdk) android device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add your native code to an existing application that is developed with the SDK. You use the NDK to build the native code, and then use the SDK to build the application as a whole - which will package up and include the libraries that the NDK built.

That application can then be used on any device it is compatible with, with regards to the Android API level, or the architectures that you compiled the native code for.